# Prove that if $f_r:M\to M,m\mapsto mr$ is surjective, then $r$ is an invertible element of a commutative ring $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, where $R$ is a commutative artinian ring with unity and let $f_r: M \to M$ be multiplication by $r$, that is, $f_r: m\mapsto rm, r\in R$.  Prove that if $f_r$ is surjective, then $r$ is an invertible  element of $R$.

I have a sketch of the proof which I am not confident with:

Solution:  If $Mr=f_r(M)=M$, the $r$ can not belong to any of the prime ideals of $R$.  In fact $r$ can not be in any of the maximal ideals of $R$.  Otherwise, if $r$ belonged to any of the prime ideals, then it would be nilpotent and in this case $0=Mr^n=M$ for some  $n$.  This contradicts the fact that $Mr=M$.   This implies that $r$ is an invertible element of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly not true.

Let $R=F\times F$ where $F$ is a field, and $M=\{0\}\times F$, and $r=(0,1)$.

Then obviously $e$ is the identity transformation on $M$, and $e$ is not a unit of $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $r=3$. The map $f_r\colon M\to M$ is even an isomorphism (it's actually the identity, but that's irrelevant).

Where is the bug in your attempt to a proof? There is no reason why $r$ should not belong to some prime ideal. It cannot belong to *every* prime ideal, this is true: you should be careful with your interpretation of “any”.